# Pass multiple commands in ad-hoc mode in Cisco ios_command module

Tags: ansible, ansible-ad-hoc

I would like to know how can I pass multiple `show` commands in `ios_command` module in ad-hoc mode.

Sample with just one command:

```
ansible all -m ios_command -a "commands='show version'"
```

Now here I would like to send another command, say `show run` or any other.

Any suggestions on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list and you can do it using JSON string:

```
ansible all -m ios_command -a "commands='[ \"show version\", \"show run\" ]'"
```

<sup>If you leave the spaces out, you can squeeze to `'commands=["show version","show run"]'`</sup>

Comment: Thanks I will try that and let you know

Comment: Tried it out...its not working... Getting error as Invalid input detected. Any chance that you can test it out once in your environment? I have tried all the possible combinations that I could think of, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
ansible ios-device -m ios_command -a commands="{{ lookup('file', 'commands.txt') }}" -u username -k
```

where `commands.txt` contains

`show version`

You can add more commands on each line of the 'commands.txt' file.